# Troubles in running STIP (Space-Time Interest Points) in windows

Tags: matlab, image-processing, computer-vision

I'v downloaded the windows version of STIP (space-time interest points) named stip-1.1.-winlinux.zip

I'm trying to run it from Matlab using the command:

```
system('bin\stipdet.exe -f data\walk-simple.avi -o data\walk-simple-stip2.txt');
```

But I'm getting the following error: "Could not initialize capturing from data\walk-simple.avi... "

It seems that it somehow trying to capture a video from the camera instead of using the input file.

I'm working on windows8 with Matlab 2013a. I already added all the dll's needed in order to run the package. The input file exist, so that certainly not the problem.

Has anyone managed to run in on windows? Any help will be greatly values as I'm quite stuck and really have no idea how to solve it.

Thanks,

Gil.

Comment: Does it work if you run it from the command prompt, rather than from MATLAB?

Comment: No, it gives the same error.

Comment: Then it's probably nothing to do with how you're calling it from MATLAB but either an issue with the location of the *.avi, or the format of the command line error. Not being familiar with STIP, I can't offer further advice - I suggest you ask the makers of that program.

Answer (score 1):

Install the Xvid codec, not the DivX codec

Answer (score 1):

Installing XVid codecs worked for me. 
https://www.xvid.com/download/

Also needs OpenCV 1.0 for correct .dlls
http://opencv.org/downloads.html

Answer (score 0):

try installing DivX video codec .