# Error in running STIP (Space-Time Interest Points) in windows

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision, feature-extraction

I'v downloaded the windows version of STIP (space-time interest points).

I've tried to run it from command prompt using the command,

`bin\stipdet.exe -f data\walk-simple.avi -o data\walk-simple-stip.txt`

Then I was facing the error which was listed in the link:

[Troubles in running STIP (Space-Time Interest Points) in windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20556018/troubles-in-running-stip-space-time-interest-points-in-windows)

According to the answers to this question I downloaded and installed the Xvid codec. After installing the codec I was able to generate the STIP features for the two sample videos which are given with the code.
But on providing any other video apart from those given it generated the same error, i.e.,

"`Could not initialize capturing from data\walk-simple.avi...` "

Comment: Please anyone help..

Answer (score 0):

Install XVid codecs. I had the same issue and this cleared it up. Still having issues running an RGB .avi file though. Also make sure you're using the correct version of opencv. I'm using 1.0 and it's working fine for his example data sets.

Comment: I have mentioned in the question also that I'm able to generate features for the example dataset but the problem is that I want to generate features for my videos..@Bryan Harper

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. The solution was convert the videos using Xvid Convert.